# Exit a JPanel or a GlassPane when we click outside it

Tags: java, swing

Days ago i asked for help to put a JPanel on top of the other CardLayout panels, with the help of one of the users i achieved it using GlassPane, so thanks to him, but now i wanna close it whenever i click outside it(in other windows of the applications or components) because its stuck there until i click settings button, how can i achieve that? I have tried with focus lost and gained but that doesn't work with the panel so what am i supposed to do, here is my piece of code..

```
     JPanel settingsPanel = new JPanel();
     settingsPanel.setLayout(null);
     settingsPanel.setPreferredSize(
                new Dimension(180, 260));


     JLabel lblSettingsTitle = new JLabel("Settings");
        lblSettingsTitle.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD | 
         Font.ITALIC, 18));
        lblSettingsTitle.setBounds(5, 8, 200, 35);
        settingsPanel.add(lblSettingsTitle);

        JSeparator settingsSep = new JSeparator();
        settingsSep.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        settingsSep.setBounds(0, 48, 160, 2);
        settingsPanel.add(settingsSep);

        JPanel panelLanguage = new JPanel();
        panelLanguage.setBounds(0, 61, 200, 30);
        settingsPanel.add(panelLanguage);
        panelLanguage.setLayout(null);

        JPanel pnlLanguage = new JPanel();
        pnlLanguage.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 30);
        panelLanguage.add(pnlLanguage);
        pnlLanguage.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblLanguageIcon = new JLabel("");
        lblLanguageIcon.setIcon(new 
        ImageIcon(frmMain.class.getResource("/image/Language_20px.png")));
        lblLanguageIcon.setBounds(5, 5, 20, 20);
        pnlLanguage.add(lblLanguageIcon);

        JLabel lblLanguage = new JLabel("Choose Language");
        lblLanguage.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.ITALIC, 15));
        lblLanguage.setBounds(30, 0, 170, 30);
        pnlLanguage.add(lblLanguage);

        JPanel pnlAlbanian = new JPanel();
        pnlAlbanian.setBounds(0, 30, 200, 30);
        panelLanguage.add(pnlAlbanian);
        pnlAlbanian.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblAlbIcon = new JLabel("");
        lblAlbIcon.setIcon(new 
        ImageIcon(frmMain.class.getResource("/image/albanian.png")));
        lblAlbIcon.setBounds(20, 0, 30, 30);
        pnlAlbanian.add(lblAlbIcon);

        JLabel lblAlbanian = new JLabel("Albanian");
        lblAlbanian.setBounds(50, 0, 150, 30);
        pnlAlbanian.add(lblAlbanian);

        JPanel pnlEnglish = new JPanel();
        pnlEnglish.setBounds(0, 60, 200, 30);
        panelLanguage.add(pnlEnglish);
        pnlEnglish.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblEngIcon = new JLabel("");
        lblEngIcon.setIcon(new 
        ImageIcon(frmMain.class.getResource("/image/britain.png")));
        lblEngIcon.setBounds(20, 0, 30, 30);
        pnlEnglish.add(lblEngIcon);


        JLabel lblEnglish = new JLabel("English");
        lblEnglish.setBounds(50, 0, 150, 30);
        pnlEnglish.add(lblEnglish);

        JPanel pnlAboutUs = new JPanel();
        pnlAboutUs.setBounds(0, 120, 200, 30);
        settingsPanel.add(pnlAboutUs);
        pnlAboutUs.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblAboutIcon = new JLabel("");
        lblAboutIcon.setIcon(new 
        ImageIcon(frmMain.class.getResource("/image/About_20px.png")));
        lblAboutIcon.setBounds(5, 5, 20, 20);
        pnlAboutUs.add(lblAboutIcon);

        JLabel lblAboutUs = new JLabel("About Us");
        lblAboutUs.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.ITALIC, 15));
        lblAboutUs.setBounds(35, 0, 165, 30);
        pnlAboutUs.add(lblAboutUs);

        JPanel pnlHelp = new JPanel();
        pnlHelp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    Help obj=new Help();
                    getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
                    obj.setVisible(true);
                    obj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                }
        });
        pnlHelp.setLayout(null);
        pnlHelp.setBounds(0, 91, 200, 30);
        settingsPanel.add(pnlHelp);

        JLabel lblHelpIcon = new JLabel("");
        lblHelpIcon.setIcon(new 
        ImageIcon(frmMain.class.getResource("/image/Help_20px.png")));
        lblHelpIcon.setBounds(5, 5, 20, 20);
        pnlHelp.add(lblHelpIcon);

        JLabel lblHelp = new JLabel("Help");
        lblHelp.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.ITALIC, 15));
        lblHelp.setBounds(35, 0, 165, 30);
        pnlHelp.add(lblHelp);




        ((JComponent) getGlassPane()).setLayout(new 
         FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 260, 390));
        ((JComponent) getGlassPane()).add(settingsPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);




    JLabel lblSettings = new JLabel("");
    lblSettings.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    lblSettings.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            getGlassPane().setVisible(!getGlassPane().isVisible());

        }

    });
    lblSettings.setToolTipText("Settings");
   lblSettings.setIcon(new 
   ImageIcon(frmMain.class.getResource("/image/Settings_24px.png")));
    lblSettings.setBounds(210, 600, 50, 50);
    menuPanel.add(lblSettings);
```

Comment: define "outside of it", clicking in another window of your application, or somewhere not related to your application?

Comment: Anywhere outside the settingsPanel in other windows of my application, not outside the application

Comment: you could keep an observer, that publishes where has been clicked, and add a listener in your jpanel to check whether or not to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've slightly modified my previous example, so the settings panel goes closed on the click outside it.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class RightSidePanel implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Right side panel");
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // next two lines are not required
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frm.setContentPane(contentPanel);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("It's the first card panel"), "first");
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("It's the second card panel"), "second");
        // add some components to provide some width and height for the panel.
        mainPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(600));
        mainPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(300));
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        JPanel settingsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        settingsPanel.add(new JLabel("Here is the settings panel!"));
        settingsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(settingsPanel.getPreferredSize().width, 300));
        JButton settingsButton = new JButton("Show settings"); // move this line up
        ((JComponent) frm.getGlassPane()).setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 0, 0));
        ((JComponent) frm.getGlassPane()).add(settingsPanel);
        // added code here
        frm.getGlassPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // check whether the click on the glass pane.
                Component c = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(frm.getGlassPane(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (e.getComponent().equals(c)) {
                    updateButton(frm, settingsButton);
                }
            }
        });
        // end of the added code
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 10, 10));
        settingsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // move the method content to a separate method
                updateButton(frm, settingsButton);
            }
        });
        JButton switchButton = new JButton("Show second");
        switchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) mainPanel.getLayout();
                if (mainPanel.getComponent(0).isVisible()) {
                    cl.show(mainPanel, "second");
                    switchButton.setText("Show first");
                } else {
                    cl.show(mainPanel, "first");
                    switchButton.setText("Show second");
                }
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(switchButton);
        buttonPanel.add(settingsButton);
        frm.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frm.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void updateButton(JFrame frm, JButton settingsButton) {
        frm.getGlassPane().setVisible(!frm.getGlassPane().isVisible());
        if (frm.getGlassPane().isVisible()) {
            settingsButton.setText("Hide settings");
        } else {
            settingsButton.setText("Show settings");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RightSidePanel());
    }
}
```